# How to compare data in SQL

Tags: sql, django

I have an application which is taking data from questionnaires users are completing on a website and inputting this into a SQL Lite database.

I'm using Django and would like to display data of users who match closest by selecting similar answers.

How could this be done?

Comment: How do you define similarity between questions? Quora used to do this using sphinxsearch : http://www.bigfastblog.com/quoras-technology-examined#the-search-box

Comment: @102254563 Can you elaborate on what kind of questionnaires you have, is it text or some kind of categories, like Yes, No or Maybe?

Comment: As written, this question is too broad.  I think you should write another question, provide sample data and desired results.  Things like "match closest" and "similar answers" may make sense to you, but out of context they can mean many things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple join conditions like this

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>

INNER JOIN <same table different name>
    ON (condition1 OR condition2 OR condition3)
```